# How to populate missing date row with next date row in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
  date  value       
01-01-2020  2       
04-01-2020  3   
05-01-2020  5       
06-01-2020  7       
05-01-2020  9
```

I want output:

```
date    value
01-01-2020  2
02-01-2020  3
03-01-2020  3
04-01-2020  3
05-01-2020  5
06-01-2020  7
07-01-2020  9
08-01-2020  9
09-01-2020  9
10-01-2020  9
```

```sql
WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT *, 
      lead(date) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS NextDate FROM Screen1
) 
SELECT
  c.Date,
  t.value
FROM Calender1 c 
JOIN cte1 t ON c.Date 
  BETWEEN t.date AND ISNULL(DATEADD(day, -1, t.NextDate), t.date)
```

I have tried this but its duplicating the previous date value.In this query i have used a calender table and joined that table with main table which has missing dates.

Comment: A calender table would be a start. What have *you* tried so far? Why didn't it work? [so] isn't a free coding service, please don't treat it like one. As a new user, I really suggest you take the [tour], and have a read of the [help]; I particularly suggest having a read of the "how to ask a good question" article.

Comment: I have tried this but its duplicating the previous date value.  WITH cte1 AS
(SELECT *, lead(date) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS NextDate
 FROM Screen1
)
SELECT  c.Date,t.value
FROM Calender1 c
JOIN cte1 t
    ON c.Date BETWEEN t.date AND ISNULL(DATEADD(day,-1,t.NextDate),t.date)

Comment: Put your attempt(s) in the question, @Shivam , as an [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have calendar table. Then you can find the next available value using CROSS APPLY and fill that value.

```sql
declare @table table(dateval date, val int)

insert into @table
values 
('2020-01-01',  2),
('2020-01-04',  3 ),  
('2020-01-05',  5 ),      
('2020-01-06',  7 ),      
('2020-01-10',  9)

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2020-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2020-01-31'

;WITH Cal(n) AS
(
SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM Cal
WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
),
FnlDt(d) AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate) FROM Cal
)


SELECT f.d, t.val
FROM FnlDt as f
CROSS APPLY
(select top 1 val from 
@table as t
where t.dateval >= f.d
order by t.dateval) as t(val)
```

| d | val |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 |
| 2020-01-02 | 3 |
| 2020-01-03 | 3 |
| 2020-01-04 | 3 |
| 2020-01-05 | 5 |
| 2020-01-06 | 7 |
| 2020-01-07 | 9 |
| 2020-01-08 | 9 |
| 2020-01-09 | 9 |
| 2020-01-10 | 9 |